# Update navbar after success login or logout redirection

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a simple authentication app in React, the problem is that when the user logs in, he is redirected to his profile but my navbar component is not rendering correctly. Only applies the changes after I refresh the page but not when is directly redirected by the request.

**App Component:**

```
function App() {

  const auth = useAuth();

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        {auth.auth ? <Navbar/> : <NotAuthNavbar/>}
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Register/>}/>
            <Route path="/profile"
                  element={
                    <PrivateRoute>
                      <Profile/>
                    </PrivateRoute>
                  }
            />
            <Route path="/confirm-register/:tokenConfirm" element={<ConfirmRegister/>}/>
            <Route path="/registered" element={<RegisterMessage/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Auth Custom Hook:**

```
const useAuth = () => {

    const [auth,setAuth] = useState(null);
    const [user,setUser] = useState({});

    const isAuth = async() => {
        await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/logged-user/',{withCredentials:true})
        .then(res => {
            setUser(res.data);
            setAuth(true);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setAuth(false);
        });
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        isAuth();
    },[auth])

    return{
        auth:auth,
        user:user
    }
}
export default useAuth;
```

**Navbar and NotAuthNavbar:**

```
///Navbar.jsx
const Navbar = () => {

    const auth = useAuth();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const logout = async() =>{
        await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/logout/",{withCredentials:true})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            navigate('/login');
            return;
        })
    }

    return(
        <section>
            <div className="navbar">
                <ul className="navbar-menu">
                    <li><Link to={"/dashboard"}>Dashboard</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={"/profile"}>Welcome {auth.user.username}</Link></li>
                    <li><button type='button' onClick={logout}>Logout</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <Outlet />
        </section>
        )
}

export default Navbar;

/// NotAuthNavbar.jsx
const NotAuthNavbar = () => {


    return(
        <section>
            <div className="navbar">
                <ul className="navbar-menu">
                    <li><Link to={"/dashboard"}>Dashboard</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={"/signup"}>Sign Up</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={"/login"}>Sign In</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <Outlet />
        </section>
        )
}

export default NotAuthNavbar;
```

When user log in, I redirect to his profile with Navigate by react-router-dom.

I don't know how to update the navbar after login and logout. I can't stop thinking there is a small details that I don't see, but I'm have been stucked in this for few hours.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is the function of login

```
const login = async(e) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/signin/",{
            email:email.email,
            password:password.password
        },{
            withCredentials:true,
        })
        .then(res => {
            setIsSubmitted(true);
            if(res.status === 200){
                alert('!LOGGED');
                navigate('/profile');
                return res.data;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            let parsedErrors = [];
            parsedErrors = JSON.parse(error.request.response);

            setHandleErrors(parsedErrors);

            setIsSubmitted(true);
        })
    }
```

Comment: React hooks don't share state. Move the `useAuth` state into a React context and provide that to the app. The `useAuth` hook should then use the `useContext` hook to access the single auth state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Issue

React hooks don't share state.

## Solution

Move the `useAuth` state into a React context and provide that to the app. The `useAuth` hook should then use the `useContext` hook to access the single auth state.

Example:

Create an `AuthContext`, provider, and hook.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext({
  auth: null,
  setAuth: () => {},
  user: null,
});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          'http://localhost:5000/api/logged-user/',
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
      
        setUser(res.data);
      } catch(error) {
        setUser(null);
      };
    };

    isAuth();
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth, user }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

Wrap the `App` component with the `AuthProvider` component.

```
import AuthProvider from "../path/to/AuthContext";

...

<AuthProvider>
  <App />
</AuthProvider>
```

Now that there's a single `auth` and `user` state the `useAuth` hooks all reference the same state.

### App

```
function App() {
  const { auth } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Router>
      {auth ? <Navbar /> : <NotAuthNavbar />}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Register />} />
        <Route
          path="/profile"
          element={(
            <PrivateRoute>
              <Profile />
            </PrivateRoute>
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/confirm-register/:tokenConfirm" element={<ConfirmRegister />} />
        <Route path="/registered" element={<RegisterMessage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

### Navbar

Access the `setAuth` updater function to set `auth` false upon successful logout.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const { setAuth, user } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const logout = async () => {
    const res await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/logout/",
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
    console.log(res.data);
    setAuth(false);
    navigate('/login');
  }

  return(
    <section>
      <div className="navbar">
        <ul className="navbar-menu">
          <li><Link to={"/dashboard"}>Dashboard</Link></li>
          <li><Link to={"/profile"}>Welcome {user.username}</Link></li>
          <li><button type='button' onClick={logout}>Logout</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </section>
  );
};
```

### Component using `login` function

Use the `useAuth` hook to access the `setAuth` updater function and set `auth` true upon successful authentication.

```
const { setAuth } = useAuth();

...

const login = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/signin/",
      {
        email: email.email,
        password: password.password
      },
      {
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );

    if (res.status === 200) {
      alert('!LOGGED');
      setAuth(true);
      navigate('/profile');
    }
  } catch(error) {
    setHandleErrors(JSON.parse(error.request.response));
  } finally {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
  }
}
```

Note: It's anti-pattern to mix `async/await` with Promise chains. Generally you should select one or the other. I've used `async/await` with `try/catch` to handle rejected promises and other errors that may occur.

Comment: Great answer! Suggesting a global state manager is worth though, in my opinion.

Comment: @CesarePolonara Yes, naturally, if the app is *already* using global state, integrating this auth state into it is sensible.

Comment: @DrewReese This works 100%. Thank you very much!. Use a global state to control user authentication Is a good practice?, or the way I am using Is not very recommendable?, or it is the only way to do it?

Comment: @JosePabloArancibiaLinker At a certain point when enough components care about "state", having a singular state object is good practice. Whether it's a global Context, Redux (*built on the Context API*), Mobx, etc... these are all abstractions of the pattern of [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: This is brilliant, please update the typo `export useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);` to `export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);` and it will be perfect

Comment: @Rox Whoops, thanks for the feedback. Just know that you can also make suggested edits. Cheers.

Comment: Ah that's awesome, wasn't even aware of a "suggest edits" feature... Stackoverflow could do with a bit of UI / UX haha. Thanks man, just suggested a couple of edits